# "Not Responding" while in function

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

I've tried to create a python script using tkinter which will move my mouse every 170 second (intended, 17 seconds for test in the code).

Target:

I want 2 buttons:

- 1st to start the function that will move mouse, wait 170 seconds, run again etc.
- 2nd to turn off that function without closing the window from my .pyw script

  Problem:

  I don't think the 2nd button will work as intended, and the main problem is that during `time.sleep(17)` the window goes "Not Responding.

  **PLEASE NOTE THAT I'M ABSOLUTE BEGINNER IN PYTHON**

  Please see my code below:

```
import time
import tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()

root.title("MouMo")
root.geometry("300x100")
root.configure(bg='white')

def turnon():
    onbtn['state'] = Tk.DISABLED
    while ( onbtn['state'] == Tk.DISABLED ) :
        pyautogui.moveRel(0, 30, duration=1)
        pyautogui.moveRel(0, -30, duration=1)
        time.sleep(17)
            

def turnoff():
    onbtn['state'] = Tk.NORMAL

onbtn = Tk.Button(root, text="ON", padx=50, command = turnon)
offbtn = Tk.Button(root, text="OFF", padx=50, command = turnoff)

onbtn.pack(side="left")
offbtn.pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to use while loop and `time.sleep()` in a tkinter application because it will block tkinter `mainloop()` from handling pending events and updates.

Use `.after()` to replace the while loop and `sleep()`:

```py
def turnon(first=True):
    if first:
        onbtn['state'] = Tk.DISABLED
        onbtn.update_idletasks() # make the state updated immediately
    if onbtn['state'] == Tk.DISABLED:
        pyautogui.moveRel(0, 30, duration=1)
        pyautogui.moveRel(0, -30, duration=1)
        # execute turnon() after 17 seconds
        onbtn.after(17000, turnon, False)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I can not Upvote your answer because my reputation is to low :)) but your answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RobertCenusa You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Done! One more question please: could you confirm that the Off Button will really stop the function and the loop will not run forever in background, causing CPU problems? Thanks

Comment: @RobertCenusa Yes the `Off` button will stop the `after()` task.